# Quartz.net scheduler gets garbage collected

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net, cron-task

Currently have 12 jobs running using quartz.net.

The first 10 jobs need to run every 30 minutes.
The second 2 jobs need to run every 3 minutes.

The problem is after the 2 jobs that run every 3minutes are done. The program stops working. It doesn't crash the console window is still responding but the app doesn't fire jobs anymore.

I assume that this is because the scheduler got garbage collected. Does somebody have a solution to this?

StartAsync:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var scheduler = await GetScheduler();
    await scheduler.Start();

    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetAbsenceJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(AbsenceJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetAddressJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(AddressJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetCustomerJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(CustomerJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetDriverJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(DriverJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetPlanCombJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(PlanCombJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetPlanGroupJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(PlanGroupJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetSupplierJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(SupplierJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetTrailerJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(TrailerJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetTransportTypeJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(TransportTypeJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetVehicleJob(), GetDefaultTrigger(nameof(VehicleJob)));

    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetImportFilesJob(), GetImportTrigger(nameof(ImportFilesJob)));
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetExtractFilesJob(), GetImportTrigger(nameof(ExtractFilesJob)));

}
```

GetSchedular

```
private static async Task<IScheduler> GetScheduler()
{
    var props = new NameValueCollection {
        { "quartz.threadPool.threadCount",      "20" },
        { "quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold",   "60000" },
        { "quartz.serializer.type",             "binary" },
        { "quartz.scheduler.instanceName",      "SynchroScheduler"},
        { "quartz.jobStore.type",               "Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" },
        { "quartz.threadPool.type",             "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" }
    };
    var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
    var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

    return scheduler;
}
```

EDIT:

How the service is started:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
                {
                    configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    configHost.AddJsonFile(Text.Hostsettings, optional: true);
                    configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: Text.Prefix);
                    configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    configApp.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    configApp.AddJsonFile(Text.Appsettings, optional: true);
                    configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                    configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: Text.Prefix);
                    configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddLogging();
                    services.Configure<SynchroDbOptions>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("SynchoDbOptions"));
                    services.AddHostedService<DbSyncService>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
                {
                    configLogging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            configLogging.AddConsole();

        })
        .UseConsoleLifetime()
        .Build();

host.RunAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. `ScheduleJob` just registers the job, it doesn't wait for it to execute. At some point the garbage collector will come along and reclaim the memory, and as I recall there is a finalizer that de-schedules any jobs. Therefore you need to store the `IScheduler` instance you're scheduling into.

One option would be to return the `IScheduler` to the caller so that they can decide how to store it:

```
public async Task<IScheduler> StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
    ...
    return scheduler;
}
```

Another is to just have your instance method store it in a member variable and have the class manage the lifetime of the scheduler. Bases on your comments this is probably the best approach.

As your class `DBSyncService` is registered as a service then just add a member variable:

```
private IScheduler _scheduler;
```

And set it in `StartAsync` and that will mean that the lifetime of the scheduler is goverened by the lifetime of the service, which is in turn managed by the lifetime of you service container.

Comment: So thanks for the response. I can follow the logic however I have one problem. The StartAsync functionality starts in a different file using a HostBuilder.
I have edited my question so could you take a look as to how I would catch the scheduler?

Comment: @BjornPijpops - The code that shows howthe service starts doesn't call either of the methods in your original example, so it's hard to explain how to catch scheduler. Are you able to register the `IScheduler` as a service so that is stays alive for the duration of the app?

Comment: So the StartAsync method that you told me to alter an return a value to is impossible. The method is inherited from IHostedService and that service only has async Task StartAsync en not async Task<T> StartAsync. Therefor it is impossible for me to return the scheduler

Comment: @BjornPijpops - So it sounds like what you need to do is habe your `DbSyncService` store the `IScheduler` as a member variable.

Comment: so I would have to change it so instead of having: var scheduler = GetScheduler(); Declare a private static IScheduler scheduler. and assign it the scheduler?

Comment: ok so that is what I did. I did make the _scheduler static. Is that a problem? Will be trying again right now!

Comment: Seems to work like a charm! Thanks for the fast response!